# how to throw a 403 error in Apache CXF - Java

Tags: java, apache, exception, error-handling, cxf

I am using the following code based on having an interceptor. When check returns true I want to throw a 403 error:

```
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message arg0) throws Fault {


        HttpServletRequest request = context.getHttpServletRequest();
        if(check(request)){
        // currently not working
                throw "Fault";
        }
```

I want to throw a 403 error. How do I go about doing that from this situation?

I am a little confused about how "throws fault" works.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CXF will default the status code to 500 for a Fault, but you can set it with [Fault.setStatusCode](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/interceptor/Fault.html#setStatusCode%28int%29).  For example

```
Fault fault = new Fault(new Exception("Exception message"));
fault.setStatusCode(403);
throw fault;
```

Comment: I get "The constructor Fault(String) is undefined"

Comment: Oops, I messed up the Fault constructor.  Looks like it needs to take an Exception.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: hmm : "The method setStatusCode(int) is undefined for the type Fault" ... I am using java with apache dxf

Comment: What version of CXF are you using?  That code will compile for me, and produces the expected 403 status code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered throwing:

```
throw new javax.ws.rs.ForbiddenException();
```

It returns http 403.

Comment: That's a JAX-RS exception, you need to be using a JAX-RS implementation for it to be recognized like RESTEasy.