# Write message content and response code in Apache CXF Interceptor

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, jax-rs

I am trying to make my web service secure by making one of the methods require HTTP Basic authentication. In order to do this, I've implemented a custom Interceptor called `LoginInterceptor` that checks the requested URL, and if it corresponds to a method called `open`, it checks the message header for the username and password.

If there are no authentication fields in the header, the response code is set to `HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED`, and if the username or password is incorrect, the response code is set to `HTTP_FORBIDDEN`.  Here's the code:

```
public LoginInterceptor() {
     super(Phase.RECEIVE);
     addAfter(RequestInterceptor.class.getName()); //another custom interceptor, for some simple redirections.
}

public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
     String requestURI = message.get(Message.REQUEST_URI).toString();
     String methodKeyword = requestURI.substring("localhost".length()+1).split("/")[0];

     if(methodKeyword.equals("open")) {
          AuthorizationPolicy policy = message.get(AuthorizationPolicy.class);
          if(policy == null) {
              sendErrorResponse(message, HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
              return;
          }

          //userPasswords is a hashmap of usernames and passwords.     
          String realPassword = userPasswords.get(policy.getUserName());
          if (realPassword == null || !realPassword.equals(policy.getPassword())) {
                    sendErrorResponse(message, HttpURLConnection.HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
          }
     }
}

//This is where the response code is set, and this is where I'd like to write the response message.
private void sendErrorResponse(Message message, int responseCode) {
    Message outMessage = getOutMessage(message);
    outMessage.put(Message.RESPONSE_CODE, responseCode);

    // Set the response headers
    Map responseHeaders = (Map) message.get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS);

    if (responseHeaders != null) {
        responseHeaders.put("Content-Type", Arrays.asList("text/html"));
        responseHeaders.put("Content-Length", Arrays.asList(String.valueOf("0")));
    }

    message.getInterceptorChain().abort();

    try {
        getConduit(message).prepare(outMessage);
        close(outMessage);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Message getOutMessage(Message inMessage) {
    Exchange exchange = inMessage.getExchange();
    Message outMessage = exchange.getOutMessage();

    if (outMessage == null) {
            Endpoint endpoint = exchange.get(Endpoint.class);
            outMessage = endpoint.getBinding().createMessage();
            exchange.setOutMessage(outMessage);
    }

    outMessage.putAll(inMessage);

    return outMessage;

}

//Not actually sure what this does. Copied from a tutorial online. Any explanation is welcome
private Conduit getConduit(Message inMessage) throws IOException {
    Exchange exchange = inMessage.getExchange();
    Conduit conduit = exchange.getDestination().getBackChannel(inMessage);
    exchange.setConduit(conduit);
    return conduit;
}

private void close(Message outMessage) throws IOException {
    OutputStream os = outMessage.getContent(OutputStream.class);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
}
```

This works fine, however, I want to also return a message in the response, something like "incorrect username or password". I've tried, from within the `sendErrorResponse` method, doing:

`outMessage.setContent(String.class, "incorrect username or password")`
and I set the content-length to `"incorrect username or password".length()`. This doesn't work, I guess because the Apache CXF Messages use `InputStream`s and `OutputStream`s.

So I tried:

```
OutputStream os = outMessage.getContent(OutputStream.class);
try {
    os.write("incorrect username or password".getBytes() );
    outMessage.setContent(OutputStream.class, os);
 } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

This doesn't work either. When stepping through with a debugger, I notice that `os` is `null` When testing with Postman, I get:

> Could not get any response This seems to be like an error connecting
>   to `http://localhost:9090/launcher/open`. The response status was 0.
>   Check out the W3C XMLHttpRequest Level 2 spec for more details about
>   when this happens.

Pressing ctrl+shif+c (opening up dev tools) in Chrome, and checking the networks tab, I see:

```
"ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH"
```

I've tried using an XMLStreamWriter, but that wans't any better.

Questions:

- I can return the correct response code (401 Unauthorized and 403 forbidden), but how do I return a message in the response body?
- Do I need to specifically extend a particular OutInterceptor like JASRXOutInterceptor in order to modify the message content?
- I tried using a JAASInterceptor before, but I didn't manage to get that working. Could someone show me how to implement it that way, if that's somehow easier?
- I could also just throw a fault like this: `throw new Fault("incorrect username or password", Logger.getGlobal());`, but then the HTTP response code would be 500. I'd prefer to return a proper 401 or 403 response.

Note:

Right now I'm still using HTTP for the transport layer. Once I fix this, I'll change to HTTPS.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, what I wanted to do is return a fault with a HTTP response code of 401 (unauthorized) or 403 (forbidden) instead of 500 (server error). Turns out Apache CXF provides a simple way of doing that, using the `Fault.setStatusCode(int) method`, as I found from this question on Stack Overflow: [how to throw a 403 error in Apache CXF - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354839/how-to-throw-a-403-error-in-apache-cxf-java)

So this is what my handleMessage method looks like now:

```
public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        String requestURI = message.get(Message.REQUEST_URI).toString();
        String methodKeyword = requestURI.substring("localhost".length()+1).split("/")[0];

        if(methodKeyword.equals("open")) {
            AuthorizationPolicy policy = message.get(AuthorizationPolicy.class);

            if(policy == null) {
                Fault fault = new Fault("incorrect username or password", Logger.getGlobal());
                fault.setStatusCode(401);
                throw fault;
            }

            String realPassword = userPasswords.get(policy.getUserName());
            if (realPassword == null || !realPassword.equals(policy.getPassword())) {
                Fault fault = new Fault("incorrect username or password", Logger.getGlobal());
                fault.setStatusCode(403);
                throw fault;
            }
        }
    }
```

I removed the other methods, they were unnecessary.